# Possible causes for a gas tankless water heater sometimes shutting down

Tags: water-heater, tankless

I have a Rheem ECOH2OODVLN gas tankless water heater. I'm not sure of it's exact age as it came with the house, but it's in good condition (clean, no dust, no visible damage, etc.).

The situation: starting about 3 months ago, it started to have a problem shutting off while water is flowing. I'd turn on the hot water, and 10% of the time the water would never get hot. Turning it off and waiting for a few minutes usually fixed the problem. The problem got worse, and now it produces hot water about 10% of the time. When it fails to heat water it *sometimes* shows error code 11 (ignition failure).

When I turn on the hot water I see that the flame does ignite (looking through the viewing window), but it is shut off for some reason. Sometimes you can feel the water getting warm then it shuts off. If the gas remains turned on for 3-4 minutes, it will continue to produce hot water until turned off. So it is igniting, just being shut off most of the time.

What I've done:

1. Replaced the igniter
2. Checked the igniter works (started with it pulled)
3. Pulled and cleaned flame sensors
4. Had the gas company come and check pressure and leaks - all good
5. Flushed with a descaler (it was way overdue)
6. Checked for gas/incomplete combustion - only in normal amounts when starting, and only in exhaust (so it looks like no issue with valves)

I'm going to run a descaling cycle again and pull the flame sensors today and check that they work with a multimeter, but I'm not sure what else could be happening. That it continues to work once started makes me think that the flame sensor (or the board that drives it) is the problem, but I'm not sure. The gas company guy said it smelled 'electrical' when opened (I don't have much of a sense of smell), but the boards look fine.

What else should I check/do? How to diagnose other issues?

Comment: https://www.rheem.com/product/performance-condensing-94-direct-vent-indoor-ecoh200dvln-2

Comment: manual & troubleshooting chart, page 23 : https://cdn.globalimageserver.com/FetchDocument.aspx?ID=B0E7F470-A620-46FC-B4F3-D63B312F61E7

Comment: i would suspect build-up or corrosion on the oxygen sensor.